# Is DXA will import with legacy publishing on Web 8

Tags: dxa, web8, publishing, topology-manager, dxa-2.0

We are using SDL Web 8 with legacy publishing and we are planning to work on DXA 2.0 .

Is DXA will import in SDL Web 8 with legacy publishing or it required Topology Manager mandatory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DXA 2.0 only supports publishing via the Topology Manager, when we started supporting Web 8, we moved to full support of it and ditched the deprecated legacy publishing model to gain full advantage of the features in Web 8.

This means you have to use Topology Manager and need to either run the `ttm-prepare.ps1` script before the DXA CMS import (preferred), or you need to setup a Topology yourself, but then you have to use the same identifiers as used in the DXA import packages (otherwise the import will fail).

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want you to want to import using **cms-import.ps1**, if you want to import DXA Example Site Publication to your CMS then it's by default it's required Topology Manager mapping.

In that case, It's required to run the **ttm-prepare.ps1** script before the DXA CMS import.

It has following importType options:

```
# Use "all-publications" if you want to import DXA into a new Publication Blueprint tree in your CMS.
# Use "master-only" if you want to only import DXA Master items into an existing Publication. See also -masterPublication parameter.
# Use "example-publication" if you want to import DXA Example Publications (110 DXA Site Type, 200 Example Content and 400 Example Site) into an existing BluePrint. See also -masterPublication and
-rootPublication parameters.
# Use "rights-permissions" if you want to import DXA rights and permissions in your CMS (do this after importing all Publications).
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: It doesn't depend. DXA 2.0 only supports Publishing via the Topology Manager.